# What does $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ mean?

Tags: reference-request, notation, terminology

What does $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ mean?

It's hard to find what this means from the literature without knowing what it is a called. Is this weak convergence?

Comment: yes, it usually indicates weak convergence

Comment: I'll post a community wiki answer :)

Comment: @Giovanni Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\rightharpoonup$ is usually used to indicate weak convergence.